# How can I send an HTTP PUT request in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, rest, put

I am trying to send a PUT request to a particular URL, and have thus far been unsuccessful in doing so.

If I were doing it through an HTTP requester GUI, such as [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httprequester/) one, it would be as simple as doing a PUT on the following url:

`http://www.mywebsite.com:port/Application?key=apikey&id=id&option=enable|disable`

Note that a port number is specified in the above request. I will also need to do that when submitting the request through the ruby code.

How can I replicate such a request in Ruby?

Comment: Use the restclient gem; there's a PUT method. Without any specifics regarding the issues you say you're having, not sure what else to say.

Comment: restclient is excellent, if you don't want more dependencies you can use net/http which is part of the standard library: http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html

Comment: I tried restclient as well as net/http and was unsuccessful using both. I'm sure it's because of some error/lack of knowledge on my part. A further explanation of using either would be greatly appreciated. I would prefer net/http over restclient.

Comment: It would be clearer if you could show us exactly the service you are trying to access. Are you sure you mean PUT request? It looks more like you want a GET request to receive some data?

Comment: Hi peterept, unfortunately it is for a work and I can't really disclose more than that. However, it was a put request, not get. I already had get requests implemented haha

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
require 'net/http'

port = 8080
host = "127.0.0.1"
path = "/Application?key=apikey&id=id&option=enable"

req = Net::HTTP::Put.new(path, initheader = { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'})
req.body = "whatever"
response = Net::HTTP.new(host, port).start {|http| http.request(req) }
puts response.code
```

Larry's answer helped point me in the right direction. A little more digging helped me find a more elegant solution guided by this answer.

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('www.mywebsite.com', port)
response = http.send_request('PUT', '/path/from/host?id=id&option=enable|disable')
```

Comment: Where is this would I include the arguments for my request?

Comment: Larry, this is very helpful. Thanks for taking the time to do that.

Comment: @finiteloop: `send_request` takes  a third parameter for the data you're 'PUT'ing

Comment: send_request also takes an optional fourth parameter for custom headers.