# Query server with PUT method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I will replace my command line

```
`curl -XPUT 'host:port/url' -d '{"val": "some_json"}'̀
```

by a Rails command, and get the result...

Somewhere like this :

```
response = call('put', 'host:port/url', '{"val" : "some_json"}')
```

Is there any predefined method to do this in Rails, or some gem ?
I know the command `get` of HTTP, but I will do a 'PUT' method.

```
Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('host:port/url'))
```

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Have you tried doing this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403728/how-can-i-send-an-http-put-request-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) to send any standard http requests.

Here is a way, you can connect to any url ( http / https ), with any valid http methods with or without parameters.

```
def universal_connector(api_url, api_parameters={}, method="Get")
  # Do raise Error, if url is invalid and Method is invalid

  uri = URI(api_url)
  req = eval("Net::HTTP::#{method.capitalize}.new('#{uri}')")
  req.set_form_data(api_parameters)                                                                                                    
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,:use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
   response = http.request(req)
     return response.body
  end
end
```

There are many alternatives available as well. Specifically, [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday). Also, [read this](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2011/07/faraday-advanced-http/) before making a choice.

Answer (score 0):

`#get` is just a simple shortcut for the whole code (`Net::HTTP` Ruby library tends to be very verbose). However, [`Net::HTTP` perfectly supports `PUT` requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403728/how-can-i-send-an-http-put-request-in-ruby).

Another alternative is to use an HTTP client as a wrapper. The most common alternatives are [HTTParty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/) and [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday).

```
HTTParty.put('host:port/url', { body: {"val" : "some_json"} })
```

---

As a side note, please keep in mind that Rails is a framework, not a programming language. Your question is about how to perform an HTTP PUT request in Ruby, not Rails. It's important to understand the difference.